# Flask, serving Static File and or folder inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, flask, jinja2

I m trying to insert the following static url for a static folder inside a javascript so it can properly load a saved file, but i m still facing error.

Here is what happens.

the normal file location is http://localhost/static/uploads/filename.ext  but with the following javascript, it fetch the location based on the views' url_prefix='/media'  hence the url it fetches is http://localhost/media/static/uploads/filename.ext

here is the following code:

```
    <script>
$(function(){
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            url: 'upload',
            dataType: 'json',
            add: function (e, data) {
                data.submit();
            },
            success:function(response,status) {
            console.log(response.filename);
            var filePath = 'static/uploads/' + response.filename;

            $('#imgUpload').attr('src',filePath);
            $('#filePath').val(filePath);
                console.log('success');
            },
            error:function(error){
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
})
```

I m trying to replace,

```
var filePath = 'static/uploads/' + response.filename;
```

with

```
var filePath =  {{ url_for('static', filename='/uploads/') }} + response.filename;
```

but with no success. The original filename settings leads to the Blueprint  url_prefix, which i wanted to bypass.

#### Edit

Here is my Views

```
@media.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        extension = os.path.splitext(file.filename)[1]
        f_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + extension
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], f_name))
        return json.dumps({'filename':f_name})
```

Comment: @JohnMee, No file is being served with the javascript's filePath, aparrently, javascript is serving file as http://localhost/media/static/uploads/filename while the original file locaiton is localhost/static/uploads/filename

Comment: there might be some connection between the usage of `@media.route` and the undesired `media` insertion, but still you haven't told us the actual error message.  What is the exact text of the error message that has you stumped?

Comment: @JohnMee, i didn't made myself clear earlier.  here is what happens.
with media blueprint the file url is http://localhost/media/static/uploads/filename    but the real location of the file name should be http://localhost/static/uploads/filename so pointing the first url produce a 404 error

Comment: What's `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']` set to?

Comment: @JohnMee 
`UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/static/uploads')
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102969/discussion-between-afidegnum-and-john-mee).

Answer (score 1):

There are two paths to consider here and you need to pay close attention to which you're using where:

1. the absolute filepath on the server eg: `/opt/myapp/media/upload/<filename>`, and
2. the relative urlpath on the client eg: `https://localhost/static/upload/<filename>`

Your easiest solution may be to simply return the filename, without any directory preamples, then prepend the appropriate directory for the context in which you use it.

So in the python you can still return 'somefile.jpg' with:

```
return json.dumps({'filename': f_name})
```

And in the javascript you can reference '/static/uploads/somefile.jpg' with:

```
var filepath = '/static/uploads/' + response.filename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have fixed the issue, I have stripped the url_prefix parameters so i can call from the root url path. to avoid the previous issue.